# Is there a game called Sonic: The Next Level?

Tags: game-identification, sonic-the-hedgehog-series

I've been watching the docuseries "High Score" on Netflix, and in episode 4, the Sega episode, there are several clips that refer to something called "Sonic: The Next Level" and a Level called "Gust Planet Zone":

[image: Sonic the Hedgehog: Next Level]

Online, I see references to a ROM with this name, and some hacks of Sonic Mania with a level by that name, but no reference to anything official.

Is this an actual Sonic game I missed, or did the show show a clip of a ROM hack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Sonic: The next level" is a ROM hack made by MarkeyJester and originally posted [here](https://forums.sonicretro.org/index.php?threads/sonic-1-the-next-level.34835/)